# C++ 11 std thread sumation with atomic very slow

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, atomic, stdthread

I wanted to learn to use C++ 11 std::threads with VS2012 and I wrote a very simple C++ console program with two threads which just increment a counter. I also want to test the performance difference when two threads are used. Test program is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<long long> sum(0);
//long long sum;

using namespace std;

const int RANGE = 100000000;

void test_without_threds()
{
    sum = 0;
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < RANGE; k++)
        sum ++ ;
}

void call_from_thread(int tid) 
{
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < RANGE; k++)
        sum ++ ;
}

void test_with_2_threds()
{
    std::thread t[2];
    sum = 0;
    //Launch a group of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        t[i] = std::thread(call_from_thread, i);
    }

    //Join the threads with the main thread
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start, end;

    cout << "-----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "test without threds()\n";

    start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    test_without_threds();
    end = chrono::system_clock::now();

    chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;

    cout << "finished calculation for "
              << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "ms.\n";

    cout << "sum:\t" << sum << "\n";\

    cout << "-----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "test with 2_threds\n";

    start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    test_with_2_threds();
    end = chrono::system_clock::now();

    cout << "finished calculation for "
              << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "ms.\n";

    cout << "sum:\t" << sum << "\n";\

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I use for the counter just the long long variable (which is commented) I get value which is different from the correct - 100000000 instead of 200000000. I am not sure why is that and I suppose that the two threads are changing the counter at the same time, but I am not sure how it happens really because ++ is just a very simple instruction. It seems that the threads are caching the sum variable at beginning. Performance is 110 ms with two threads vs 200 ms for one thread.

So the correct way according to documentation is to use std::atomic. However now the performance is much worse for both cases as about 3300 ms without threads and 15820 ms with threads. What is the correct way to use std::atomic in this case?

Comment: Are you compiling in Release mode?

Comment: Without the atomics, your program has undefined behaviour. With atomics, it's slower because you now have two threads contending for the same variable all the time. Multithreading is very costly and only worth it in certain special situations.

Comment: It is much slower even without threads. What other option I have to make it work correct and fast?

Comment: VS2012 also had a rather inefficient `std::atomic` implementation. VS2013 is much better.

Comment: Replace the loop with `sum += RANGE;` and `atomic` performance won't matter nearly as much.  The general rule for concurrency is to minimize contention, not maximize it pointlessly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not sure why is that and I suppose that the two threads are changing the counter at the same time, but I am not sure how it happens really because ++ is just a very simple instruction.

Each thread is pulling the value of `sum` into a register, incrementing the register, and finally writing it back to memory at the end of the loop.

> So the correct way according to documentation is to use std::atomic. However now the performance is much worse for both cases as about 3300 ms without threads and 15820 ms with threads. What is the correct way to use std::atomic in this case?

You're paying for the synchronization `std::atomic` provides. It won't be nearly as fast as using an un-synchronized integer, though you can get a small improvement to performance by refining the memory order of the add:

```
sum.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

In this particular case, you're compiling for x86 and operating on a 64-bit integer. This means that the compiler has to generate code to update the value in two 32-bit operations; if you change the target platform to x64, the compiler will generate code to do the increment in a single 64-bit operation.

As a general rule, the solution to problems like this is to reduce the number of writes to shared data.

Comment: how do you generate a 64 bit atomic operation out of two 32 bit ones?

Comment: fetch_add didn't work for me much faster, again with atomic calculation is as much slower, even without threads, I suppose that both processors are using their own registers? they copy the value at begin and after a time back to the shared memory.

Comment: @Yakk: It involves spinning with the `lock cmpxchg8b` instruction, which does an atomic compare and exchange on 8 bytes of memory. The addition is carried out on two 32-bit registers via an `add` and `adc` (add with carry) instruction.

Comment: @BajMile: Using an `std::atomic` ensures that the threads have to commit their result back to memory after each operation. In this case, the two threads are stepping on each other's toes. They're both fighting over who gets to update the same piece of memory.

Comment: @collin that is a 64 bit atomic operation that updates the value.  I guess there are two 32 bit machine code ops to generate the value to update, granted.  Atomic operations are not decomposible was my point.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a couple of problems. First of all, all the "inputs" involved are compile-time constants, so a good compiler can pre-compute the value for the single-threaded code, so (regardless of the value you give for `range`) it shows as running in 0 ms.

Second, you're sharing a single variable (`sum`) between all the threads, forcing all of their accesses to be synchronized at that point. Without synchronization, that gives undefined behavior. As you've already found, synchronizing the access to that variable is *quite* expensive, so you usually want to avoid it if at all reasonable.

One way to do that is to use a separate subtotal for each thread, so they can all do their additions in parallel, without synchronizing, the adding together the individual results at the end.

Another point is to ensure against false sharing. False sharing arises when two (or more) threads are writing to data that really is separate, but has been allocated in the same cache line. In this case, access to the memory can be serialized even though (as already noted) you don't have any data actually shared between the threads.

Based on those factors, I've rewritten your code slightly to create a separate `sum` variable for each thread. Those variables are of a `class` type that gives (fairly) direct access to the data, but does stop the optimizer from seeing that it can do the whole computation at compile-time, so we end up comparing one thread to 4 (which reminds me: I did increase the number of threads from 2 to 4, since I'm using a quad-core machine). I moved that number into a const variable though, so it should be easy to test with different numbers of threads.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <conio.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <numeric>

const int num_threads = 4;

struct val {
    long long sum;
    int pad[2];

    val &operator=(long long i) { sum = i; return *this; }
    operator long long &() { return sum; }
    operator long long() const { return sum; }
};

val sum[num_threads];

using namespace std;

const int RANGE = 100000000;

void test_without_threds()
{
    sum[0] = 0LL;
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < num_threads; j++)
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < RANGE; k++)
        sum[0] ++ ;
}

void call_from_thread(int tid) 
{
    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < RANGE; k++)
        sum[tid] ++ ;
}

void test_with_threads()
{
    std::thread t[num_threads];
    std::fill_n(sum, num_threads, 0);
    //Launch a group of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i] = std::thread(call_from_thread, i);
    }

    //Join the threads with the main thread
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }
    long long total = std::accumulate(std::begin(sum), std::end(sum), 0LL);
}

int main()
{
    chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> start, end;

    cout << "-----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "test without threds()\n";

    start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    test_without_threds();
    end = chrono::system_clock::now();

    chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;

    cout << "finished calculation for "
              << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "ms.\n";

    cout << "sum:\t" << sum << "\n";\

    cout << "-----------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "test with threads\n";

    start = chrono::system_clock::now();
    test_with_threads();
    end = chrono::system_clock::now();

    cout << "finished calculation for "
              << chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
              << "ms.\n";

    cout << "sum:\t" << sum << "\n";\

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, my results are closer to what I'd guess you hoped for:

```
-----------------------------------------
test without threds()
finished calculation for 78ms.
sum:    000000013FCBC370
-----------------------------------------
test with threads
finished calculation for 15ms.
sum:    000000013FCBC370
```

... the sums are identical, but N threads increases speed by a factor of approximately N (up to the number of cores available).

Comment: Yes, if threads are using its own counters it will work. There is no way to work asyncroneosly and it to work correctly and fast. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use prefix increment, which will give performance improvement. 
Test on my machine, std::memory_order_relaxed does not give any advantage.